# XSLT nested for Loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSLT and facing a typical problem. Below is the problem details. I need the result from ItemB (as many times ItemB) where the attribute BNum id is matched to ANum id and the output will be concatenation of attribute VAR1 id and ANum id.

Looping the objects is the main problem I am facing.

Example Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myData>
<ItemA>
   <VAR1 id="1234">
     <ANum id = "3333"/>
     <ANum id = "5555"/>
     <ANum id = "6666"/>
   </VAR1>
   <VAR1 id="7B62">
     <ANum id = "4444"/>
   </VAR1>
</ItemA>
<ItemB>
   <BNum id = "6666"/>
</ItemB>
<ItemB>
   <BNum id = "4444"/>
</ItemB>
</myData>
```

Desired Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <result>
     <ItemC>
       <CNum id = "1234-6666"/>
      </ItemC>
     <ItemC>
       <CNum id = "7B62-4444"/>
     </ItemC>
    </result>
```

I tried with the below code-

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:for-each select="myData/ItemB">
                <ItemC>
                    <CNum>
                        <xsl:value-of select="BNum"/>
                        <xsl:if test="../ItemA/VAR1/ANum/@id = BNum/@id">
                            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(../ItemA/VAR1/@id,'-',BNum/@id)"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </CNum>
                </ItemC>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I am getting the output as-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
 <ItemC>
   <CNum id = "1234-6666"/>
  </ItemC>
 <ItemC>
   <CNum id = "1234-4444"/>
 </ItemC>
</result>
```

The last value of ItemC is wrong and need help in correcting it.

Comment: **1.** Pease post your Input and the expected output within your question **as code** (not as pictures). -- **2.** Show us what you've tried so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you. -- **3.** Please pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 - not both.

Comment: Hello Micheal,
Thanks a lot for the help. As per the question, I need the number of ItemC should be equal to number of item B. Could you help with it.

Comment: My stylesheet below will create exactly one `itemC`  for each `ItemB` in the given input. So I don't understand what your current problem is.

Comment: The output you show in your edited post is not the output received as the result of performing the transformation: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/6qVRKvK

Comment: Kindly ignore the last edits. There was a issue from my end. I am really thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-references are best handled by using a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key). Then the problem becomes rather trivial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="v1" match="VAR1" use="ANum/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/myData">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="ItemB/BNum">
            <ItemC>
                <CNum id="{key('v1', @id)/@id}-{@id}"/>
            </ItemC>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Note**: to understand this, you may also need to learn about [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates).